# delete taking really long time! mysql

Tags: sql, mysql

i am doing this:

```
delete calibration_2009 from
calibration_2009 join batchinfo_2009
on calibration_2009.rowid = batchinfo_2009.rowid
where batchinfo_2009.reporttime like '%2010%';
```

both tables have about 500k lines of data
i suspect that 250k match the criteria to be deleted

so far it has been running for 2 hours!!! is there something wrong?

dev.mysql.com says i should do this:

```
If you are deleting many rows from a large table, you may exceed the lock table size for an InnoDB table. To avoid this problem, or simply to minimize the time that the table remains locked, the following strategy (which does not use DELETE at all) might be helpful:

Select the rows not to be deleted into an empty table that has the same structure as the original table:

INSERT INTO t_copy SELECT * FROM t WHERE ... ;
Use RENAME TABLE to atomically move the original table out of the way and rename the copy to the original name:

RENAME TABLE t TO t_old, t_copy TO t;
Drop the original table:

DROP TABLE t_old;
```

how do i do this with my current statement?

Comment: Thats probably just because 250+k is alot of data to delete, and would take a while

Comment: possible duplicate of [quickest way of deleting data from mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2884385/quickest-way-of-deleting-data-from-mysql)

Comment: Generally I do a select count(*) from ... prior to running an actual delete to ensure I'm getting at least the right quantity of lines and a select * ... limit 100 (or so) to make sure the lines look right.  If you're running this in a transaction you might consider aborting and checking that you're really deleting what you expect.

Comment: 2 hours is indeed a long time for this.  It should be more like 2 minutes (give or take several minutes).

Comment: I am trying to delete records from a table with 27 million rows. I don't know how many I'm deleting but I'm at nearly 14 minutes now. My query is based on a column with no index, deleting records `< $some_date`. Not sure if I should kill process and try a delete based on primary key now.

Comment: I killed the process and used `SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 7000000,10` just as a guess of where I want to detel from. It was right around the date I wanted, so I issued the `DELETE`statement based on the `PK` and deleted 7,000,006 rows in 3 minutes 31.31 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Some things to think about and try:**

- Are you sure that rowid is your primary key?
- Are they the same data types?
- Do you have an index build on it?
- Wrap the delete in a transaction
- Confirm you don't have any active triggers from the delete.
- Can you post the table schema?
- Also, run the query through the [Query Analyser](http://www.mysql.com/products/enterprise/query.html) to confirm the joins are happening properly

---

**SCRIPT TO COPY TABLE:**

```
INSERT INTO calibration_2009_copy
SELECT calibration_2009.* 
FROM calibration_2009 
 JOIN batchinfo_2009 
   ON calibration_2009.rowid = batchinfo_2009.rowid
WHERE batchinfo_2009.reporttime not like '%2010%';

RENAME TABLE calibration_2009 TO calibration_2009_old;
RENAME TABLE calibration_2009_copy TO calibration_2009;

DROP TABLE calibration_2009_old;
```

Comment: Glad to help.  Did you use the Copy Table Script, or find what was causing the problem in the first place?

Comment: i used the piece of code you had suggested. i guess i was just trying to delete too many rows and my select statement took too long i dont know

Answer (score 1):

Try adding an [index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html) for batchinfo_2009.reporttime and rowid
also see if there are any table locks in case of using MyISAM

Answer (score 0):

I don;t know about mysql but this '%2010%' would guarantee a table scan in SQl Server.  That would certainly slow things down.

Comment: True, but 500k rows is not a lot to scan, just a few seconds, unless his machine is "REAL SLOW".  On my machine I scan just over 80K rows/second

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE batchinfo_2009.reporttime NOT LIKE '%2010%';
```

This is probably the reason the query is so slow. Using LIKE, especially with a wildcard in the beginning of the string, will cause the query to not use an index on `reporttime`.

A better query would be:

```
DELETE calibration_2009
FROM calibration_2009
JOIN batchinfo_2009
ON calibration_2009.rowid = batchinfo_2009.rowid
WHERE batchinfo_2009.reporttime NOT BETWEEN MAKE_DATE(2010, 1) AND MAKE_DATE(2010, 365);
#`repporttime` is a TIMESTAMP
```

This would perform a range scan on `repporttime` using an index.